# In Magento how to get AccessToken and Access Secret Token

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

I have installed the Advanced Rest Client to my chrome. From my magento i can get consumer key and secret key from admin panel. I have tried to get token from the link http://term.ie/oauth/example/client.php but it returns in the following way.. Here there is no token key..

```
request url: ://192.168.1.101:8000/magento/admin/oauth/token ?oauth_version=1.0&oauth_nonce=XXXXXXXXX&oauth_timestamp=XXXXXXX&oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxxx&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=xxxxxxxxx%3D
OAuthRequest Object
(
    [parameters:OAuthRequest:private] => Array
        (
            [oauth_version] => 1.0
            [oauth_nonce] => XXXXXXXXXX
            [oauth_timestamp] => XXXXXXX
            [oauth_consumer_key] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            [oauth_signature_method] => HMAC-SHA1
            [oauth_signature] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
        )

    [http_method:OAuthRequest:private] => GET
    [http_url:OAuthRequest:private] => 192.168.1.101:8010/magento/admin/oauth/token 
    [base_string] => GET&%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.101%2Fmagento%2Fadmin%2Foauth%2Ftoken%20&oauth_consumer_key%XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26oauth_nonce%XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26oauth_signature_method%XXXXXXXXXX%26oauth_timestamp%XXXXXXXXX%26oauth_version%3D1.0
)
```

So suggest me how can I get access token and access secret token....

Comment: I think you have achieve the task as guided ,...pls post the answer it would be help..

Answer (score 2):

according to me you have already created **admin role for REST** & **OAUTH Consumers** so i am skiping it.

Create below test.php file in root. replace the CONSUMERKEY and CONSUMERSECRET with your values.

```
<?php
/**

* Example of update product record via Magento REST API. OAuth authorization is used

*/

$callbackUrl = "http://yourhost/test.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://yourhost/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://yourhost/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://yourhost/api/rest';
$consumerKey = '[your consumer key here]';
$consumerSecret = '[your consumer Secret here]';



echo "<pre/>";

session_start();

if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {

$_SESSION['state'] = 0;

}

try {

$authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;

$oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);

$oauthClient->enableDebug();

$oauthClient->disableSSLChecks();



if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {

$requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
echo "<pre>";print_r($requestToken);die();
$_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];

$_SESSION['state'] = 1;

header("Location: " . $adminAuthorizationUrl . "?oauth_token=" . $requestToken['oauth_token']);

exit;

}
```

?>

and the output above should be array

```
Array
(
    [oauth_token] => "tokenkey"
    [oauth_token_secret] => "token secret"
    [oauth_callback_confirmed] => true
)
```

hope this help you.

Comment: I am using Magento 1.9, How to get customer list using REST API? @shivam